# Can I detect if an expression is a mutable variable using Rust's macro repetition?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

```
macro_rules! log {
    ($($x:expr),*) => {
        {
            $(
             //how to detect $x in the Macro repetition?

            )*
        }
    };
}
```

I don't want to use `($($x:ident),*)`. The `log!` macro can log the expression and then I want to match the variable type.

Comment: Hi there. It's currently really hard for us to understand what exactly you are asking. What is your goal exactly? Please [edit] your question to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

Macros only can access token streams, and cannot say anything more about those tokens, apart from what is explicitly given to the macro.

For example, consider this code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foo: i32 = 1;
    my_macro!(foo);
}
```

The only information available to the macro `my_macro` is the input token `foo`. It can match that `foo` is is an identifier but it can't say anything more about it. The fact that there is mutable binding called `foo`, or that this binding is an `i32` are just not available inside the macro.